# Cannot access my django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

Urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from basic_code.settings import STATIC_ROOT

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/' , include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'media(?P<path>. *)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':          settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
(r'static(?P<path>. *)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
url(r'^$', 'contact.views.home'),
url(r'^static/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes' : True}),
url(r'^templates/$', 'templates.welcome', name="welcome"),
```

)

settings.py installed apps

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

I have syncdb and collectstatic before making edits to urls and settings. 
Now terminal shows

```
$ python2.7 manage.py collectstatic
Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

when I collect static.

and when I go to www.website.com/admin I get:

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named templates
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.website.com/admin/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named templates
Exception Location: /home/user/webapps/appname/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you properly [configure the staticfiles app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your module `templates`

Problem is in following line:

```
url(r'^templates/$', 'templates.welcome', name="welcome"),
```

Comment: how so? 

I added that line to be able to access my welcome.html page under the templates folder.

I may be wrong however, this is my first website.

Comment: You need to actually [write a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view) to render your welcome.html file.

Comment: Use generic views: `TemplateView.as_view(template_name="welcome.html")`

Comment: where do I place TemplateView.as_view(template_name="welcome.html")?

Comment: Read about views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: sk1p: here is my views.py: _______

    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import RequestContext, loader
    from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

    from .forms import SignUpForm


    def home(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_sign_up = form.save(commit=False)
        new_sign_up.save()
        return render(request,'welcome.html')
    
    return render_to_response('form.html', locals(),      context_instance=RequestContext(request))